# Why Python says "'int' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I'm trying execute my code and my interpreter says this. Where is my error?

```
import cv2
videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture('opal.avi')
fps = videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
size = (int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
videoW = (cv2.VideoWriter('opal2.avi',
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC('I', '4', '2', '0'), fps, size))
success, frame = videoCapture.read()
while success:  # Loop until there are no more frames.
    videoW.write(frame)
    success, frame = videoCapture.read()
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question? It should show exactly which line has the error.

Comment: Please post the entire error message you are getting, including line numbers

Comment: "Why Python says “'int' object is not callable”?" because int's are not callable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC('I', '4', '2', '0') will generate the error.

CAP_PROP_FOURCC is a constant, ie an int.

You can't call an int

```
3("hello") => impossible "int" object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Error like that are often due to this type of line:

```
success, frame = videoCapture.read()
```

This line is quite similar to:

```
aRet = videoCapture.read()
success = aRet[0]
frame = aRet[1]
```

if videoCapture.read() return an int, then the line:

```
success = aRet[0]
```

becomes an iteration on an int, and that is impossible, so your error.

So before doing that, check your return value is of the list type...

Comment: That would result in "iterable", not "callable".

Comment: I'm sorry, the interpreter says on the line 7:
cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC('I', '4', '2', '0'), fps, size))